# Change values on the x and y axis

Tags: zedgraph

Right now the values on both x and y axis are starting from 0, 0.1, 0.2 ..., 1, like seen on the image. The problem is that my graph is starting to draw when x = 3, so I cannot see it, since x only goes to 1. Is it possible to change what values are shown on the 2 axis?

So fx. to have the values go like 100, 200, 300, ..., 900, etc? Cus there will be situations where I will need the x and y values to be large

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly.!

If you want to change the X Axis Min/Max value, try this..

```
ZedGraph.GraphPane myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;

myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = 10.0;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = 100.0;

myPane.AxisChange();
zedGraphControl1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Yea, that's exactly what I meant. Thanks